# Find files accessible outside of my organization

Tags: regex, google-drive-api

In the `Drive.Files.List` I can, using the `'q'` parameter, get all files a user can read/write or own. I would like to be able to use regular expression in the query value. For example set `q` to be `"not '.+@my-org.com' in writers"`.

Is such a query already supported?

Do I have another way (except invoking Drive.Permissions.List for each and every file in my Drive) to get this information from?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only account level drive API is part of the report API - activities list. This API (and admin console - audit - drive) section is only supported in the **unlimited** license. Still haven't found the proper API get the drive state (list all files metadata in the account, permissions etc.) seems that the state can only be inferred from analyzing the relevant activity events assuming the activity is not being evicted after a predefined period of time.
My conclusion, at the moment, is that there is no "root" directory at the account level. "root" is only with respect to the logged in user. 
I would be more than happy to be proved wrong.
Uri